# Google App Script Saving File to incorrect File ID

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a project where a user needs to upload a spreadsheet to either a Denied or Approved folder on a shared Google Drive.  I have created two buttons on a google sheet (one for denied requests and the other for Approved Requests) Each button is assigned to a separate script within the project that opens an upload file dialog box. The approval script has the Approved folder destination folder ID associated with it and the denied script has the Denied Folder destination ID attached to it.

The issue I am having is that the Approved Upload script works as expected and uploads the file to the correct folder in Google Drive as long as the Denied Script is not present in the project (if I delete the script and template from the project). When I add the Denied Script and template to the project, the Approved Script will only save to the Denied Folder. The denied script saves to the correct folder in the presence of the approved script.  So in other words, when the denied script and template are present, all files are saved only to the Denied folder.

I am fairly new to App Script but have some coding experience and cannot find a logical explanation for this and have spent a long time looking at it and searching for answers.  If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated

This is that code for the Approval Script:

```
function UploadApprovals(){
                                                     
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("UploadApprovalsTemplate").evaluate();   
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(template,"Approved File Upload");}

function uploadFilesToGoogleDrive(approveddata,approvedname,approvedtype){                          
  var approveddatafile = Utilities.base64Decode(approveddata);                               
  var approvedblob2 = Utilities.newBlob(approveddatafile, approvedtype, approvedname);                      
  var approvedfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1QenNvdjwzVQx8APUbx4VgySU7eOsgDSD"); 
    var approvednewFile = approvedfolder.createFile(approvedblob2);                                   
  Logger.log (approvednewFile + "Approved New File folder and file")
   var rowData = [                                                          
    approvednewFile.getName(),
    approvednewFile.getId(),
    approvednewFile.getUrl(),
    approvednewFile.getSize(),
    approvednewFile.getDateCreated()
  ];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Approved File Uploads").appendRow(rowData);     
  return approvednewFile.getUrl()                                                   
}
```

This is the Approval html Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>

    <input type="file" id="approvedfile" >
    <input type="button" id="approvedupload" value="Upload" class="action" onclick="UploadApprovedFiles()">
    <p id="msg"></p>
    
    <script >
      var fileUploader = document.getElementById("approvedfile");
      var msg = document.getElementById("msg");//for display msg
      function UploadApprovedFiles() { 
        msg.innerHTML = "Uploading Approved file..."; 
        var approvefile = fileUploader.files[0];    
        var reader = new FileReader();      
        reader.readAsDataURL(approvefile)           
        reader.onload = function(Approve) {         
          var rawLog = reader.result.split(',')[1];  
          google.script.run                  
            .withSuccessHandler(function (a) {
              msg.innerHTML = "Uploaded at <a href="+a+" target='_blank'>"+a+"</a>" ;  
            })
            .uploadFilesToGoogleDrive(rawLog, approvefile.name, approvefile.type); 
        };
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the Denial Script:

```
function UploadDenials(){                                                     
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("UploadDenialsTemplate").evaluate();   
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(template,"Denial File Upload");           
}
 
function uploadFilesToGoogleDrive(denieddata,deniedname,deniedtype){                          
  var denieddatafile = Utilities.base64Decode(denieddata);                               
  var deniedblob2 = Utilities.newBlob(denieddatafile, deniedtype, deniedname);                      
  var deniedfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1rMwm6Dy_tyGxXOqN2g2KA3Hsw4_6zhxE"); 
  var deniednewFile = deniedfolder.createFile(deniedblob2);                                   
      var rowData = [                                                          /
    deniednewFile.getName(),
    deniednewFile.getId(),
    deniednewFile.getUrl(),
    deniednewFile.getSize(),
    deniednewFile.getDateCreated()
  ];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Denied File Uploads").appendRow(rowData);     
  
  return deniednewFile.getUrl()                                                   
  
}
```

This is the Denial Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
 
    <input type="file" id="deniedfile" >
    <input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" class="action" onclick="UploadDeniedFiles()">
    <p id="msg"></p>
    
    <script >
      var fileUploader = document.getElementById("deniedfile");
      var msg = document.getElementById("msg");
      function UploadDeniedFiles() { 
        msg.innerHTML = "Uploading Denied file..."; 
        var denyfile = fileUploader.files[0];    
        var reader = new FileReader(denyfile);       
        reader.readAsDataURL(denyfile)          
        reader.onload = function(Deny) {         
          var rawLog = reader.result.split(',')[1];  
          google.script.run                  
            .withSuccessHandler(function (b) {
              msg.innerHTML = "Uploaded at <a href="+b+" target='_blank'>"+b+"</a>" ;  
            })
            .uploadFilesToGoogleDrive(rawLog, denyfile.name, denyfile.type); 
        };
    }
    </script>
  </body>
```

Initially, I thought it may be an issue with variables, so I made them all unique.  I have checked the buttons on the sheet to ensure that they are Assigned to the Correct Scripts.  I added the wording in the upload messaging in the dialog box to determine that it was uploading either an Approval or denial.

I'm stumped because I cannot understand how the approval script is using the Denial folder ID when saving off file.

Comment: It would probably be good to strip this down to the absolute minimum amount of code that could be involved (i.e. the html)

Comment: I have played with the html and added some additional logging to the two templates.  What I am seeing is that it seems that all the logic is passing through the UploadApprovals script  up until it hits the function uploadFilesToGoogleDrive.  My log items after that step appear to be coming from the UploadDenials script for some reason. There is nothing calling that script so I have no idea why it would be processing there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the function name

> uploadFilesToGoogleDrive

twice in one project?

This cannot work out. Change one name.